# NetLogo: Multiple colors with the scale-color reporter

Tags: netlogo

Is there a way to get the `scale-color` reporter to work with multiple colors instead of just one?  I'm trying to get multiple groups of patches to be different colors instead of being just different shades of the same color.

```
set m (1)
loop [
      if m > 5000 [stop]
      let targetedGroup patches with [population = m]
      ask targetedGroup [set pcolor scale-color [red green blue] population 1 50]
      set m (m + 1)
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `scale-color` with multiple colors, but you can do that kind of thing with the built-in [palette extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/palette.html). Something like this might do what you want:

```
palette:scale-gradient [[255 0 0] [0 255 0] [0 0 255]] population 1 50
```